# Handling multiple developers in one solution on TFS

Tags: tfs, branch, branching-and-merging

We have a solution containing many projects and our team work on different areas of our overall software product. Before starting work, they make a development branch and work in there. When the developer has finished their work, they add/remove any projects necessary and commit the solution and merge it into the main branch.

When this merge takes place, we encounter an issue where new projects have been given the same ID in solutions from different development branches. This causes merge conflicts when we re-integrate the development branch into the main branch. Is there an elegant way to deal with this problem in TFS?

Our workaround at present is to make our own copy of the solution in our development branches, merge the development branch into the main line and then manually make any changes to the master solution in the main line. This gets round the issue of duplicate IDs being allocated to projects in the solution.

Comment: Are you saying that the developers create a new solution on their branch only including the project(s) they need and then check that in?  It sounds like you need to break the solution up into distinct solutions for particular parts of the system.

Comment: Hi discens, are you referring to our workaround described in the final paragraph. If so, no, we make a copy of the entire 'master' solution, complete our work and check that in. We then complete any changes made in our personal solution in the 'master' solution.

I appreciate it is rather messy!